# Insert data from text file in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to read a `france` text file that is stored as ANSI.
Part of the text file should be stored on mysql Database.

Everything is ok but i am getting strange characters like this:

> No 2720 č
>   or like this
>   B?timent

here is my update statement:

```
// field is on mysql DB as text/utf8mb4_general_ci

$sqlupd = "UPDATE table SET field='$field' WHERE id='$id'";
$dataupd = mysql_query($sqlupd);
```

thanks!!!

Comment: Please check if your database field's Charset & Collation type 'UTF8_unicode_ci'? if not, please set it to UTF8_unicode_ci

Comment: ok i will try that!!!

Comment: now i am getting only a string until the first strange charcter. The rest of string is empty! The charset is set "Varchar" and the Collation is set as UTF8_unicode_ci.

Comment: If the charset of the tables is set and you will get the issue of blank record, please try to use: mysql_set_charset('UTF8', $link_identifier)

Comment: i tried with mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link_identifier); and mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); unfortunately with same result.

Comment: i used utf8_encode("UPDATE table SET field='$field' WHERE id='$id'"); and that worked. thank you!!!

Comment: That will come back and bite you if the file truly is ANSI encoded; ANSI is not utf8. I have no idea what a "france text file" is.